# Как вычислить приближенные значения двух интегралов при разных шагах сетки

Tags: java

Как вычислить приближенное значение интеграла при шаге сетки 1 и при более мелком шаге сетки 0,5 так чтоб, если разность двух последовательных приближений интеграла функции достаточно мала, то завершаем алгоритм и возвращаем текущее приближение в качестве результата.
Иначе возвращаемся к шагу 2.
У меня не получается написать код так чтоб если разность велика двух интегралов то второй интеграл автоматически увеличивал шаги и сравнивал с первым пока разность не будет достаточно мала

```
public class Integral { 

public static void main(String[] args) { 
   DoubleUnaryOperator f = new DoubleUnaryOperator(); 
   System.out.println(integrate(f , 0 , 100));
}

public static double integrate(DoubleUnaryOperator f , double a , double b){

//количество прямоугольников от a до b  
   int aTob = 10; //количество шагов до b  
   double step = (b - a) / aTob; //(step = 10)  
   double result1 = f.applyAsDouble(step); //result1 = 10 steps step = step * 2;  
   double result2 = f.applyAsDouble(step);  
   while ((result2 - result1) > 0.5)  
     {  
       ????? //не могу написать код, который автоматом увеличит значение result2 b при этом сократить приближение  
     }  
   return result2;
}
```

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста,ваш пример формулы и кода?

Comment: @Dred - 
        //количество прямоугольников от a до b
        int aTob = 10;
        //количество шагов до b
        double step = (b - a) / aTob; //(step = 10)

        double result1 = f.applyAsDouble(step); //result1 = 10 steps
        step = step * 2;double result2 = f.applyAsDouble(step); 

        while ((result2  - result1) > 0.5) {
           ????? //не могу написать код, который автоматом увеличит значение result2 b при этом сократить приближение
        }
        return result2;

Comment: @GiorgiNishnianidze я перекинул твой код в пост - посмотри, все ли правильно

Comment: @GiorgiNishnianidze, А можно саму формулу интеграла, по которой вычислить надо и что такое `f.applyAsDouble(step);` Чем является `f`? Также, судя по измененному вопросу, `result1` и `result2` всегда равны

Comment: @dgzargo - да, все правильно

Comment: @Dred - public class Integral {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoubleUnaryOperator f = new DoubleUnaryOperator();
        System.out.println(integrate(f , 0 , 100));

    }

    public static double integrate(DoubleUnaryOperator f , double a , double b)

Comment: @Dred f - это ссылка на объект просто

Comment: @Dred - в result1 передаем количество шага допустим 1. В result2 передаем количество шагов допустим в два раза больше. Сравниваем разницу которая должна быть меньше например 0.00001. Если результат не устраивает увеличиваем количество шагов в result2 и опять сравниваем до тех пор пока разница не будет меньше 0.00001

Answer (score 0):

Если честно, после всего написанного вами, до сих пор сложно предложить адекватное решение.

Но, возможно, вам подойдет такой ответ.

```
 int aTob = 10;
 double step = (b - a) / aTob; 
 double result1 = f.applyAsDouble(step); 
 double result2 = f.applyAsDouble(step);  
 for (int i=step;(result2 - result1) > 0.5; i++)  
   {  
     result2=step*i;
   }  
 return result2;
```